# Activate WooCommerce Image Gallery and Modal on Archive Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've scoured the internet and I know I can't be the only one. I've found this as a reference but it still does not work. I'm assuming it's because an older post and WooCommerce has changed: [Activate Woocommerce image gallery features on shop archive page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071374/activate-woocommerce-image-gallery-features-on-shop-archive-page/64787036)

I'm a bit familiar with WooCommerce so I thought I would be able to figure it out but I'm in over my head I think? I have a child theme. For the archive-product.php page I've updated the loop to pull the single-product template:

```
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    }
}

woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

The page, with a little work, is essentially now what I need it to be:
[image]

The product image, no longer has the ability - like the gallery on an actual single-product page - to open in the lightbox modal. I'm assuming that's because the archive pages strip out that javascript. So I found another post: [Activate Woocommerce image gallery features on shop archive page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071374/activate-woocommerce-image-gallery-features-on-shop-archive-page/64787036) and that doesn't seem to work either. In the screenshot, you'll also notice the "Sizing Chart" which is supposed to open as a modal also, and not just list the information below it.

I'm at a loss and would love any help for anyone who has successfully done this. I wouldn't have thought it would be as difficult as it's proven to be, but here I am.