# Product Gallery And lightbox not working in woocommerce single page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, lightbox, image-gallery

I am using custom theme and connected with Woocommerce. In single page i wish to have a woocommerce gallery with lightbox. But unfortunately my theme not support it. When i change the theme to storefront the woocommerce gallery is work fine but in my custom theme it doesn't. My files are

- index.php
- style.css
- header.php
- footer.php
- functions.php
- woocommerce.php

In functions.php i was add below coding but still isn't support it.

```
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

May i know is there any additional files required to show the woocommerce product gallery?
I am using woocommerce 5.0.0 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: This sorted the problem for me, but might depend on what's your setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071374/activate-woocommerce-image-gallery-features-on-shop-archive-page