# Show product gallery with swatches in shop/archive page WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a WooCommerce website and im using this plugin for swatches and gallery for each product variation

https://plugins.innovativewp.org/iwp-swatches/shop/

What the plugin does is, in shop or archive page it shows swatches and on click it updates the product thumbnail with the clicked product variation main image, and in single product page when clicking on swatches it updates the whole gallery with the clicked variation gallery if exists.

So, is there a way to get the same functionality in single product pages to work in shop/archive page or custom product loop ?

I’ve managed to get the main gallery, but when click on variation of course it doesn’t change, here is the code

```
<?php 
// Get product image gallery
$gallery = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
// Check if there are images in the gallery
if (!empty($gallery)) {
    echo '<div class="product-gallery-slider">';
    foreach ($gallery as $image_id) {
        echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'large') . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '">';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

I think with some JavaScript it can be done, but unfortunately I'm not any good in JS.

I also tried [Activate Woocommerce image gallery features on shop archive page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071374/activate-woocommerce-image-gallery-features-on-shop-archive-page/47506878#47506878) answer code, but didn't work for me either.

Any help would be very appreciated.